# Error para subir a github

Tags: git, github, git-push

**fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/SethConstantino99/dizenco_app.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403**

Al tratar de hacer el remote push en mi git me aparece ese error, recientemente cree una nueva cuenta personal, pero en mi computadora yo ya tenía registrada otra cuenta diferente, estoy tratando de subir un proyecto que tengo y me marca el error de arriba, ya intenté borrar el email y el user y volver a registrarlos, borrar el log del proyecto y hacerlo de nuevo, pero me sigue rechazando el push incluso usando --force al final.

Comment: si has cambiado de cuenta, entiendo que has cambiado el remote. en git puedes tener varios remote al mismo tiempo para cada proyecto. lo suyo seria añadir el remote de la nueva cuenta, y luego hacer el push. No recuerdo ahora las instrucciones, busca como añadir un nuevo remote.

Comment: prueba quitando el slash `/` del final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal como leo tu pregunta, entiendo que has cambiado el remote, y los ajustes del repositorio (o quizá los globales de git), ¿pero has cambiado tu sesión de git en el navegador? Si usas el credential-manager (como yo) para manejar el push y el pull, las credenciales las maneja el navegador de Internet, y si el navegador tiene abierta la sesión antigua, git estará intentando subir en la cuenta B, con las credenciales de la cuenta A.